# chkdsk for specific folder - win 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, chkdsk

I want to run `chkdsk` on a specific folder in Win 10.
The [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) says:

```
chkdsk [<volume>[[<path>]<filename>]] [/f] [/v] [/r] [/x] [/i] [/c] [/l[:<size>]] [/b]
```

And I tried `chkdsk d:\users\myusername\Music`, but it gives this error:

```
The drive, the path, or the file name is not valid.
```

I also tried `d:\\users...`, `D:\\users...` and `D:\users...`; bot none of them work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `chkdsk d:\users\myusername\Music\*.*`

Comment: Didn't work :\ @harrymc

Comment: @Shahriar - I had to give up. I spent time with the Microsoft Article and the Appauls article I pointed on Windows 10, 7 and 11 and cannot make a folder scan work. I have deleted my answer for the time being.

Comment: Finally, I don't think it's possible to chkdsk less than the whole partition. Whatever documentation that says otherwise is outdated and relates to some previous Windows version.

Comment: That may be somewhat true Harry, but the articles and related links were dated in 2020 and absolutely nothing worked.  Whatever, it appears (despite documentation) folder scanning does not work.

Comment: I just added the link to docs; and yes, it's for 08/28/2020.

Comment: It's strange. The parameter is completely described in the docs: *Specifies the location and name of a file or set of files that you want chkdsk to check for fragmentation. You can use the ? and * wildcard characters to specify multiple files.*

Comment: My help is quite specific. Filename is FAT/FAT32 ONLY. See `chkdsk /?`.

Comment: Damn me. I read that many times but forgot to check if it's FAT or not :|

Comment: It will be NTFS not FAT/FAT32.

Comment: Thanks @user1644677. Feel free to add an answer so I will delete mine and accept yours.

Comment: Accept your answer. But this is my new computer I've just bought, no need to ever chkdsk.  http://www.calculatormuseum.nl/calculators/kl1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad. The disk has to be FAT/FAT32. Mine is NTFS.